# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.DataSet in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

While I am getting selected value of DropdownList and assigning to DataSet I am getting the following error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.DataSet'"
Bellow is the method I use for filling the DropdownList:

```
DrdReqCode.DataSource = dt;
DrdReqCode.DataTextField = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;
DrdReqCode.DataBind();
DrdReqCode.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));
```

Getting selected value of the DropdownList:

```
 string reqcode = DrdReqCode.SelectedItem.Value;
 SQLDataProvider SqlProvider = new SQLDataProvider();
 DataSet ds = SqlProvider.GenerateTestCaseCode(reqcode);
```

GenerateTestCaseCode Method:

```
public String GenerateTestCaseCode(string Reqcode)
{       
     try
     {

        string TestCaseCode = "";

        string strsql = "select ISNULL(Max(TestCaseID),0)+1 from TestCaseMaster TM inner join RequirementMaster RM on TM.RequirementID=RM.RequirementID"
                               + " where RequestCode='" + Reqcode+ "'";

        DataSet ds = dataAccess.GetQueryData(strsql);

                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

                int MaxTestCaseCode;
                // RequestCode = projname.Substring(0, 3);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    MaxTestCaseCode = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0]);

                    TestCaseCode =Reqcode+ " -T-" + MaxTestCaseCode.ToString("000");

                }
                return TestCaseCode;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;

            }

 }
```

Comment: Check which parameter `GenerateTestCaseCode` function accepts

Comment: What output are you expecting? Your `SqlProvider.GenerateTestCaseCode`  (`public String GenerateTestCaseCode`) method returns a string and you are trying to put that into a dataset. I dont think that will ever work. Looking at the code it seems you are generating some code and returning it back to the caller. I this case you should have `string testCaseCode = SqlProvider.GenerateTestCaseCode(reqcode);`